# Can a stored procedure with table-type parameters be called in Haskell?

Tags: sql, haskell

Can a stored procedure with table-type parameters be called in Haskell? If I have the following table, type, and procedure in SQL Server, how do I call the procedure from Haskell when its argument is a table type?

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Category (
    CategoryID int,
    CategoryName nvarchar(50)
)
GO

CREATE TYPE dbo.CategoryTableType AS TABLE
    ( CategoryID int, CategoryName nvarchar(50) )
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE InsertCategories
    (@NewCategories dbo.CategoryTableType READONLY)
AS
BEGIN

INSERT INTO dbo.Category (CategoryID, CategoryName)
SELECT nc.CategoryID, nc.CategoryName FROM @NewCategories AS nc

END
```

Comment: But why? Can you use [`executeMany`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/HDBC-2.4.0.3/docs/Database-HDBC.html#v:executeMany) to insert multiple rows at once instead?

Comment: One reason is performance. One procedure call for many tends to be more efficient than many procedure calls. In other situations, it may be that the procedure in question already exists, and it can't be (readily) replaced because it's in use elsewhere, and it's not desirable to have redundant procedures.

Comment: What Haskell package are you using for database interaction?

Comment: I'm using [HDBC](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/HDBC), but any package that can get the job done is available for consideration.